IBM MQ Message stuck in queue
We are facing issue with messages getting stuck in remote queue at random instant. The application uses selectors to consume messages. The messages are consumed again if the client application is restart. We didn't face this issue if selectors are not used. How do we find the root cause and resolution.
Edit:
There are 20 listeners pointing to same queue with different selectors. When issue is encountered, there are no error logs in client app side, and only few listeners are affected and others continue to receive the message.
IBM MQ: 9.3
Client Spring boot: 3.0
com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client: 9.4.0.0
DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory);
listenerContainer.setMessageListener(eventListener);
listenerContainer.setDestinationName(queueName);
listenerContainer.setConcurrency(String.valueOf(getConcurrency(containerSuffix)));
listenerContainer.setMessageSelector(buildSelector(containerSuffix, tableName));
jmsContainerMap.put(containerSuffix, listenerContainer);
context.registerBean("container" + containerSuffix, DefaultMessageListenerContainer.class, () -> listenerContainer);
context.getBean("container" + containerSuffix, DefaultMessageListenerContainer.class).start();


Is there any browsing going on in this system? Do you have a dispatcher that browses and then schedules the getting app for example?

from my experience sometimes ibm mq broker stops distributing to async listeners. This can be a sdk issue but we tried to poll the queue with an active listener when this happened and every listener started to get messages again. you may give it a try

Hi @MoragHughson , the system has only JMS listeners not any other scheduled events or so, the message in queue will have header key and 20 possible values,  so we will have 20 listeners.

HI @binboavetonik , is there any sample on how to do such setup ? we have 20 listener pointing to same queue only with different selectors, when issue arise, few listeners stop receiving messages others continue to receive.

This could be spring related. Do you get the same behaviour when you have fewer than 20 listeners, say 10?
